# Назначение поля BaseOfData в заголовке Optional Header Standard Fields exe файла

Tags: структуры, exe

Что должно содержать поле "BaseOfData" в дополнительном заголовке "Optional Header Standard Fields", описанном здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-standard-fields-image-only если нет секций данных?
И что оно вообще должно содержать, адрес инициализированных данных или неинициал. данных?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что это поле необязательно к заполнению (чисто логически).

Comment: Я в MASM-е написал примитивную программу без секции данных и с одной импортируемой ExitProcess(). dumppe и HEX редактор мне показали, что в получившейся программе нет секции .idata, но есть .rdata. В таблице секций поле виртуального адреса .rdata указывает на секцию, которая по факту секция импорта. Так вот поле BaseOfData также указывает на секцию импорта, которая называется у них .rdata.

Comment: Из этого никаких особых выводов нельзя сделать, разве еще одни плюс в пользу предположения, что это поле ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Я изменил в рабочем ехе BaseOfData на нули и виндоус выдала окно с ошибкой "Ошибка при запуске приложения". Так что в этом поле должно быть что-то осмысленное, знать бы что...

Comment: А если смещение секции кода поставить?

Comment: Поставил смещение секции кода в 0, а смещ. сек. BaseOfData оставил нетронутым - всё работает. Потом снова BaseOfData поставил в 0 - опять ошибка.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128145/discussion-between-0zerro-and-insolor).